# How to prevent Laravel components $attributes from containing passed in variables starting with :

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to use laravel attributes with my components like https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#default-merged-attributes. In the example the `:message` variable is not included in the `$attribute` list but in my code attributes starting wiht `:` do (and I don't want them to). Here is the code and the output.

text-with-heading.blade.php

```
<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => "m-4"]) }}>
    <a href="#{{$attributes->get('id')}}">
        <h4 class="text-turquoise-500 font-semibold">
            {{ $title }}
        </h4>
    </a>
    {{ $slot }}
</div>
```

blade file calling component

```
<x-text-with-heading :title="'Aircrafts'" id="aircrafts" :test="$test">
    <div class="flex">
        <p>
              Some text here
        </p>
    </div>
</x-text-with-heading>
```

Rendered HTML (the issue is title and test appearing as attributes for the parent div)

```
<div class="m-4" title="Aircrafts" id="aircrafts" test="whatever $test is">
    <a href="#aircrafts">
        <h4 class="text-turquoise-500 font-semibold">
            Aircrafts
        </h4>
    </a>
    <div class="flex">
        <p>
            Some text here
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

The issue is that `$attributes->merge(['class' => "m-4"])` will also add `test="whatever $test is"` and `title="Aircraft"` to the rendered html. So if `$test` is not a string it causes an error, and it also adds a title attribute that I do not want.

Is there a way to exclude attributes starting with `:` from the $attributes bag, like it shows in the example in the laravel docs where `:message` is not included?

Comment: If the `test` attribute isn't mandatory, you could supply it with a default value in your blade component. I.e: `{{ $test ?? '' }}` to avoid an error in case it isn't provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use: [Retrieving & Filtering Attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#filtering-attributes)

> You may filter attributes using the `filter` method. This method accepts
> a closure which should return `true` if you wish to retain the attribute
> in the attribute bag:
>
> ```php
> {{ $attributes->filter(fn ($value, $key) => $key == 'foo') }}
> ```

##### For example:

*text-with-heading.blade.php*

```php
<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => "m-4"])->filter(fn ($value, $key) => !in_array($key, ['title', 'test'])) }}>
    <a href="#{{$attributes->get('id')}}">
        <h4 class="text-turquoise-500 font-semibold">
            {{ $title }}
        </h4>
    </a>
    {{ $slot }}
</div>
```

*Compiles down to:*

```html
<div class="m-4" id="aircrafts">
    <a href="#aircrafts">
        <h4 class="text-turquoise-500 font-semibold">
            Aircrafts
        </h4>
    </a>
    <div class="flex">
        <p>
            Some text here
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, this worked! Although I found and went with another solution using `exceptProps()` that is a bit more concise in the [laravel api docs](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/View/ComponentAttributeBag.html#method_exceptProps) so the code looks like `$attributes->exceptProps(['title', 'test'])->merge(['class' => "m-4"])`